# I WAS SENT BITCOINS IN A WRONG ADRESS ( the last digit is missing in the adresse )

Tags: transactions, blockchain, error, receiving, revert-transaction

i sent my wallet at coinbase to the sender   today
355CXardXvii8T4MNbBaQbfJD7YQNdUf5a
but the sender sent to a wrong adress 33 digits  missing the 34th digit
355CXardXvii8T4MNbBaQbfJD7YQNdUf5

will the issue be solved and the bitcoin arrive in my wallet ?
transaction was of 131,8  BTC

Answer (score 4):

355CXardXvii8T4MNbBaQbfJD7YQNdUf5 is not a valid address. It is not possible to send anything to it.

Who is the "sender" and what did you give them in return? This smells like a scam to me, if someone is claiming they accidentally sent to an address with a character missing.

Also, you're aware 131.8 BTC today is valued over 6 million USD?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like scam to me too. Nevertheless the transaction does not go through as long as this is not a valid address.

BTW you should not post the real address here...